# Get whois output in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, whois

I want to call WHOIS domain lookup services from my CodeIgniter controller and need return array output. I just discussed with WHOIS support team, they said they do not provide API call. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: try this api http://freedomainapi.com/free-whois-api.html

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. Actually i got the solution .

Comment: so if you have a solution, update your question or post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I Got Best way to call WHOIS domain lockup services

<?php
  $username="username";
  $password="password"; 
  $contents = file_get_contents("http://www.whoisxmlapi.com//whoisserver/WhoisService?domainName=google.com&username=$username&password=$password&outputFormat=JSON");
  //echo $contents;
  $res=json_decode($contents);
  if($res){
    if($res->ErrorMessage){
        echo $res->ErrorMessage->msg;
    }   
    else{
        $whoisRecord = $res->WhoisRecord;
        if($whoisRecord){
            echo "Domain name: " . print_r($whoisRecord->domainName,1) ."<br/>";
            echo "Created date: " .print_r($whoisRecord->createdDate,1) ."<br/>";
            echo "Updated date: " .print_r($whoisRecord->updatedDate,1) ."<br/>";
            if($whoisRecord->registrant)echo "Registrant: <br/><pre>" . print_r($whoisRecord->registrant->rawText, 1) ."</pre>";
            //print_r($whoisRecord);
        }
    }
  }

?>
```